# Chrome browser does not open when running TestNG test suite file using maven command on Ubuntu 14.04 Terminal

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-14.04

**Machine**: Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS

**Maven**: 3.0.5

When I execute my TestNG test suite file from Eclipse, it opens the Chrome browser and executes the tests properly. But when I execute the following command on terminal,

```
$ sudo mvn clean install -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml
```

> Since there is already some access issue with my machine, I have to
>   use `sudo` with the command.

Chrome browser just won't open and the maven log just keep on printing the following log infinitely,

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Starting webdriver on OS: Linux
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543619 (a237acd3116cac3b3f0da42a000502ce3fafcb23) on port 14536
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting webdriver on OS: Linux
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543619 (a237acd3116cac3b3f0da42a000502ce3fafcb23) on port 6694
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting webdriver on OS: Linux
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543619 (a237acd3116cac3b3f0da42a000502ce3fafcb23) on port 4991
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting webdriver on OS: Linux
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543619 (a237acd3116cac3b3f0da42a000502ce3fafcb23) on port 19892
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting webdriver on OS: Linux
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543619 (a237acd3116cac3b3f0da42a000502ce3fafcb23) on port 21613
Only local connections are allowed.
```

> However, this is working perfectly fine on Windows 10.

Does anyone have a solution for this as I am not able to find any solution for this.

Comment: just use "sudo mvn clean install" and run the test suite. It will run whole test suite.

Comment: That's what I had done. See the command in the question. The problem here is that browser doesn't open in order for selenium tests to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my issue by dockerizing my tests.

I set the `DISPLAY` from the Dockerfile using `ENV` like,

```
ENV DISPLAY :99
```

Then I executed my `run.sh` file from Docker container using `ENTRYPOINT` to start Xvfb display:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac &
```

And executed my tests after the above line in same `run.sh` file:

```
mvn clean install -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml
```

And the output of the run is:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 13506
Only local connections are allowed.
May 31, 2018 5:44:12 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
31/05/2018 05:44:16 copy_tiles: allocating first_line at size 41

[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 17.688 s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

**Edit:**

The Docker image can be found [here](https://github.com/WasiqB/docker-test-env).

Answer (score 0):

Set your system display value as given below and try running again the test.

```
You can write at the end of your .bashrc file:

export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Comment: I'll try this out and revert to you.

Comment: are you connected with multiple monitor or display to the machine. the possible values for display varies from 0 to 4. check with different value like export DISPLAY=:1 or export DISPLAY=:2, so on.

Comment: No, I'm working with my Dell Laptop with Ubuntu. Other values also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before while running on Jenkins by Maven command, I installed xvfb on Ubuntu then perfectly worked.

Install xvfb on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Then you need to add these configurations to start it well:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x16
DISPLAY=:1.0
```

And you can install it as Jenkins plugin:
Follow [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin)

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Can you please elaborate where to put this configuration? Currently I'm not looking to use Jenkins on my local.

Comment: The configurations should be executed using Terminal on Ubuntu.
About the link of Jenkins plugin you can find the instructions when you scroll down,  you have to install the plugin first then you will get the fields in the job configure part and build tab.
Did I answer your question?